# Irrational functions

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there a way to use complex analysis to graph the following function?

$$   f(x)=(-2)^x $$

Does the variable behave differently for rationals and irrationals?

I know this is usually asked the first day of any algebra class, which is why I am here on stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Euler's identity:

$e^{i x} = \cos x + i\sin x\\
e^{\pi i} = -1\\
2e^{\pi i} = -2\\
2^xe^{\pi i x} = (-2)^x\\
(-2)^x = 2^x(\cos \pi x + i\sin \pi x)$

What does this look like?  It is a log spiral in the complex plane that crosses the real axis every time x takes on an integer value.

However there are multiple solutions to:

$e^{i x} = -1$ i.e. $e^{(2n+1)\pi i} = -1$

and

$(-2)^x = 2^x(\cos (2n+1)\pi x + i\sin (2n+1)\pi x)$

would be more general.

Which means that when x is rational $(=\frac {p}{q})$ with $gcd(p,q) = 1$ there are $q$ solutions, and when $q$ is odd, one of those is real.

And infinitely many solutions when $x$ is irrational.

Comment: Thats helpful for negative x, but for x>0 there should always be real solutions.

Comment: there is a real solution when $x = \frac 12$?  What I havent considered is that there can be multiple solutions...

Comment: Why not? If you can have extra imaginary solutions, why not extra real ones as well? Such is the case with Ramanujan.

Comment: $(-2)^{\frac 12} = \{i\sqrt 2, -i\sqrt 2\}$ there are multiple solutions but no real solutions.

Comment: Thanks again. I would upvote, but alas not enough badges

Answer (score 0):

Good intuition to look in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $z=x+iy$; the function is then
$$
 f(z) = \left( -2\right)^{z}
$$
The real and imaginary components are
$$
\begin{align}
  \text{Re } f &= 2^x e^{-\pi  y} \cos (\pi  x+y \log (2))\\
  \text{Im } f &= 2^x e^{-\pi  y} \sin (\pi  x+y \log (2))\\
\end{align}
$$
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I am a math major but I dont know how do you change the variable z into x + y ?

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the other respondents. Clearly, $z=f(x)=(-2)^x$ is complex. The result, plotted on the complex plane is a spiral, as shown in the figure below for $x\in [-3,3]$.[image]